# logcat show anything except errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2.3

[image]

Look at above image I must take null point exception but I got nothing! not just in this case seems my android studio not show errors .

I try so many ways like restart adb,android studio,emulator of phone, clear cache, online sync, reset logcat and every thing I find, but still not working.

Comment: Change `Verbose` to `Error` so that only error logs will appear. Toggle it base on your needs.

Comment: `Verbose` should show errors too, It actually shows all the log types

Comment: You might try to see if the same happens in another device or emulator

Comment: @Enzokie i know that but nothing change when change verbose error or anything

Comment: @Enzokie Oops! i change my phone and it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your device phone or emulator and see what happened .

if work it mean your logcat phone is off and you must turned on it . in another cases i don't know but for Huawei following instruction will be turn on your logcat on:

```
1.Open your Dialer app and enter the following code: *#*#2846579#*#*

2.Enter the Background Settings page.

3.Click on “Log Settings”

4.enable your logcat on.

5.Reboot the phone.
```

Comment: yes that was true! i change my phone and in another phone its ok and show errors